# Can -verbose:class be running from a class?

Tags: java, jvm

I wanna know if I can run -verbose:class from a class, not in console, and to output this to a log file, an just for a specific class, 'cause I have to run this on a PROD server where i do not have access to console.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

**NO**, using command line.

This command line option is parsed during JVM startup.

[Oracle's reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/clopts-139448.html#gbmtm) didn't mention that you can change it at runtime,

but **you can try** (if it's supported by your JVM version/vendor)

Here is how:

- you can use [ClassLoadingMXBean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ClassLoadingMXBean.html#setVerbose%28boolean%29) to change this value
- modify it using JConsole:

[image: JConsole screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

> ... if I can run -verbose:class from a class ...

Yes.

```
ClassLoadingMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getClassLoadingMXBean();
mxBean.setVerbose(true);
```

> ... to output this to a log file ...

Not from within the JVM. You can't redirct this output, as this is initialised during JVM startup to `stdout` if there is a console connected to that process.

> ... just for a specific class ...

Depends what do you mean. During processing of a specific -> see first point. Only classes loaded by a specific class -> no.